# Run all scheduled tasks by ScheduledExecutorService at a lower priority than rest all other threads in application

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to run all scheduled tasks/ threads executed by `ScheduledExecutorService` at a lower priority(at `MIN_PRIORITY`) than rest all other threads in the application.  I have been doing this the following way, but is this the correct way to accomplish this ?

```
ScheduledExecutorService schdExctr = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(new ThreadFactory() {

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        return t;
    }
});
```

### EDIT:

I think a better implementation would be this:

```
private ScheduledExecutorService schdExctr = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(new ThreadFactory() {
                                            @Override
                                            public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
                                                Thread t = Executors.defaultThreadFactory().newThread(r);
                                                t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
                                                return t;
                                            }
                                        });
```

Comment: you'd better store the value of `Executors.defaultThreadFactory()` inside a member of your anonymous class, as that call creates a thread factory each time a thread is needed.

Comment: Since I m using a `newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor`hence I think only 1 thread should be created, cached & used forever ?! No??

Comment: I was thinking about 2 different situations: 1. the thread dies and it is restarted or you might want to use this in the future elsewhere and you might want to have a good implementation for it, but otherwise is a short and clean solution.

Comment: thanks, kindly update this within your answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, that is the correct way, additionally you could look at `Executors.DefaultThreadFactory` class source to see how default threads are named.

```
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread t = new Thread(group, r,
                              namePrefix + threadNumber.getAndIncrement(),
                              0);
        if (t.isDaemon())
            t.setDaemon(false);
        if (t.getPriority() != Thread.MIN_PRIORITY)
            t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
        return t;
    }
```

where `group` and `namePrefix` are:

```
        SecurityManager s = System.getSecurityManager();
        group = (s != null) ? s.getThreadGroup() :
                              Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup();
        namePrefix = "pool-" +
                      poolNumber.getAndIncrement() +
                     "-thread-";
```

and `threadNumber` is:

```
    private final AtomicInteger threadNumber = new AtomicInteger(1);.
```

In your implementation you won't be needing the `poolNumber`.

EDIT after question edit:
The solution would be:

```
    private ScheduledExecutorService schdExctr = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor(new ThreadFactory() {
        private ThreadFactory defaultThreadFactory = Executors.defaultThreadFactory();

        @Override
        public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
            Thread t = defaultThreadFactory.newThread(r);
            t.setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);
            return t;
        }
    });
```

Comment: anything else apart from threads naming, that is left  to implemented in above override ?

Comment: in the default implementation a thread group is set to the new thread and thread is set not to be a daemon thread. I am updating the answer.

Comment: IMHO I think a better way to include all this might be as I suggested by my update within question above..